# Как отсортировать элементы в списке списков?

Tags: python, сортировка, list

Например, у меня есть список:

```
[['c', 3], ['a', 1], ['b', 2]]
```

Как мне отсортировать элементы по вторым элементам в парах?
То есть должно получиться

```
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions)

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted([['c', 3], ['a', 1], ['b', 2]], key=itemgetter(1))
```

или

```
sorted([['c', 3], ['a', 1], ['b', 2]], key=lambda i: i[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

сортировать можно любой итерабельный объект, те имеющий метод  `__iter__`

в `sorted` в ключе `key`, должна быть функция, принимающая один аргумент(элемент объекта) и что либо возвращающая

`sorted` итерирует объект сортировки, вызывая key-функцию с полученным элементом

порядок элемента в итоговом отсортированном объекте, определяет то, что для него вернет key-функция,
    точнее порядок в лексикографически отсортированом списке всех результатов выполнения key-функции

```
class Int(int):
    def __iter__(self):
        yield from range(self)

def get_element(arg):
    return arg if arg > 1 else -arg

print(sorted(Int(4)))  # [0, 1, 2, 3]
print(sorted(Int(4), key=get_element))  # [1, 0, 2, 3]
```